# Line break inside react-bootstrap card title is causing card to move up

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
class AlbumEntry extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Card style={{ margin: '5px', display: 'inline-block', width: '250px', height: '500px' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={this.props.imgSrc}/>
            <Card.Body style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
                <Card.Title> {this.props.albumTitle} </Card.Title>
                <Card.Text> {this.props.albumArtist} </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go to Album </Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

}

I am having an issue with line breaks inside my card. I am trying to list rows of cards on my page, each one having a title and text as well as an image. I can get it so that the cards are the same size, BUT if the title takes more than 1 one line, it pushes that card up, so the cards are not lined up properly. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You should truncate your text.
You can do that with.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Or you can use increase the height of the card which takes up the height of two lines of title.

```
class AlbumEntry extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Card style={{ margin: '5px', display: 'inline-block', width: '250px', height: '550px', maxHeight: '550px' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={this.props.imgSrc}/>
            <Card.Body style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
                <Card.Title> {this.props.albumTitle} </Card.Title>
                <Card.Text> {this.props.albumArtist} </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go to Album </Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    );
}
}
```

You need to enforce the fixed height otherwise your cards will not be in the expected order.